# Two discrete r.v. problem, joint density

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

**Problem**

A cook needs two cans of tomatoes to make a sauce. In his cupboard he has $6$ cans: $2$ cans of tomatoes, $3$ of peas and $1$ of beans. Suppose that the cans are without the labels, so he can't distinguish among a can of tomatoes, peas or beans. He has to open the can to know what is it of, so suppose that he is not going to open more than the necessary cans to get two cans of tomatoes.

Let $X$ be the number of opened cans of peas and $Y$ the number of cans he had to open to be able to make the sauce.

a) Find the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$

b) Find the probability of the cook not having to open the can of beans knowing that he didn't open more than $5$ cans.

I had some problems to calculate the joint function. It is clear that the range of $Y$ is $R_Y=\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ and that the range of $X$ is $R_X=\{0,1,2\}$. So, I need to find $P_{XY}(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in R_X \times R_Y$.

For the values $(0,y)$, with $y=4,5,6$, it is obvious that $P_{XY}(0,y)=0$ since that if there were no cans of peas opened, then there are at most $3$ cans left. Analogously, one can deduce that the following probabilities are $0$:

$$P_{XY}(x,2), \space x=1,2,3$$ $$P_{XY}(x,3), \space x=2,3$$$$P_{XY}(x,4), \space x=0,3$$$$P_{XY}(x,5), \space x=0,1$$$$P_{XY}(x,6), \space x=0,1,2$$

I don't know how to count the cases for the other values of $R_X \times R_Y$, I would really appreciate some help with this.

I am lost with part b) as well. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I cannot determine whether $X$ is supposed to represent the random number of opened cans of **peas** or the random number of opened cans of **beans**, because curiously enough, "peans" could be a typographical error for either word.

Comment: Oh god, thanks for the remark, I meant peas.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the stopping criterion is that the second can of tomatoes is opened.  If there are three cans of peas, then it is entirely possible that all three cans could be opened before the second can of tomatoes is opened, since the final can that is selected could be the second tomato can.

The most direct way to compute the joint distribution is to consider the set of all permutations of the six cans, which we will label $$\{T_1, T_2, P_1, P_2, P_3, B\}.$$  There are $6! = 720$ such permutations, and each represents a unique order in which the cook **plans** to open the cans.  Thus each permutation is equally likely.  But in many of these cases, the cook doesn't actually open all of the cans; he stops the moment both $T_1$ and $T_2$ have been opened.

Clearly, there are $2! 4! = 48$ ways to permute the six cans so that $T_1$ and $T_2$ appear in some order as the first two cans in the sequence.  In all of these outcomes, $X = 0$:  no cans of peas are opened before both tomato cans are found.  Thus, $$\Pr[(X,Y) = (0,2)] = \frac{48}{720} = \frac{1}{15}.$$

Next, there are $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4! = 96$ arrangements of the first three cans such that the third can opened is the second can of tomatoes.  This is because there are $2$ ways to choose one of the tomato cans to be the third can in the sequence, $2$ ways to position the other tomato can before the third can, and $4!$ remaining non-tomato cans from which to select the remaining open spots.  Of these, $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3! = 24$ result in no cans of peas being chosen (i.e., the bean can being one of the first three cans).  So we have $$\Pr[(X,Y) = (0,3)] = \frac{24}{720} = \frac{1}{30}, \quad \Pr[(X,Y) = (1,3)] = \frac{96-24}{720} = \frac{1}{10}.$$  Next, there are $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4! = 144$ ways for $Y = 4$, that is, to require opening exactly $4$ cans.  Since $4$ cans are opened and only three cans are not peas, this means the minimum number of cans of peas opened is $1$, and the number of such permutations is $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 3! = 72$, because there are $2 \cdot 3$ ways to position the two tomato cans, $2$ ways to position the can of beans among the remaining two spots among the four cans, and $3!$ ways to order the peas among the remaining spots.  And note the maximum $X$ is $2$ when $Y = 4$, since at least two of the four cans must be tomatoes.  Hence $$\Pr[(X,Y) = (1,4)] = \frac{72}{720} = \frac{1}{10}, \quad \Pr[(X,Y) = (2,4)] = \frac{144-72}{720} = \frac{1}{10}.$$  I leave it to you as an exercise to show that the remaining possible outcomes are $$(X,Y) \in \{(2,5), (3,5), (3,6)\},$$ and to compute their probabilities.

---

If one is using *Mathematica*, here is a single command that calculates the joint probability distribution:

```
{First[#], Last[#]/6!} & /@ Sort[Tally[{Count[#, {p, _}], 
  Length[#]} & /@ (Take[#, Last[Position[#, {t, _}]][[1]]] & /@ 
  Permutations[{{t, 1}, {t, 2}, {p, 1}, {p, 2}, {p, 3}, {b, 1}}])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2 cans of tomatoes, 3  of peas and 1  of beans

$Y$ is the number of cans opened until the 2 cans of tomatoes are open.   We measure the probability of selecting 1 from 2 tomato cans and $y-2$ from the 4 others in some arrangement out of the ways to select $y-1$ from $6$ cans, times the conditioned probability of selecting the 1 tomato can from the $7-y$ remaining.

$$\mathsf P(Y=y) ~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom 21 \dbinom {4} {y-2}}{\dbinom{6}{y-1}(7-y)}\Big[y\in\{2,3,4,5,6\}\Big]$$

$X$ is the number of peas opened during the process.  We modify the above to include selection of $x$ from $3$ pea cans

$$\mathsf P(Y=y, X=x) ~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom 21 \dbinom {3}{x}\color{silver}{\dbinom 1 {y-2-x}}}{\dbinom{6}{y-1}(7-y)}\Big[2\leq y\leq 6, \max(0,y{-}3)\leq x\leq \min(y{-}2,3)\Big]$$

Giving the tableau:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c:c:c:c:c|}\hline Y \backslash X & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
 2 & \tfrac 1{15} & \times & \times & \times \\ \hdashline
 3 & \color{red}{ \tfrac 1{30} } & \tfrac 1{10} & \times & \times \\ \hdashline
 4 & \times & \color{red}{ \tfrac 1{10} }& \tfrac 1{10} & \times \\ \hdashline
 5 & \times & \times & \color{red}{ \tfrac 1{5} }& \tfrac 1{30}  \\ \hdashline
 6 & \times & \times & \times & \color{red}{ \tfrac 1 {3} }\\ \hline \end{array}$$

Those marked in red are where the beans have to be opened.